# Не получается нужного результата при объединении запроса

Tags: база-данных, запрос, firebird, interbase

Есть запрос:

```
select distinct m.*, f.WORD_SATELLITE as WORD_SATELLITE from 
MAIN_TABLE m
left join FEATURES f ON
m.FEATURES_ID = f.MAIN_TABLE_ID
order by m.ID
```

он объединяет две таблицы, но в таблице «*FEATURES*», есть поле «*DESCRIPTION*».
Мне нужно получить все записи из «*MAIN_TABLE*» в связке с записями из «*FEATURES*», но с полем у которого **«DESCRIPTION» = «*satellite*»**.

Получаются дубли строк «*MAIN_TABLE*», т.к.  в «FEATURES» хранятся еще записи с «*DESCRIPTION*» = «*voice*» и «*DESCRIPTION*» = «*image*» у которых одинаковые значения «f.MAIN_TABLE_ID».

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.
Если вставить в запрос условие «*DESCRIPTION*» = «*satellite*», то из «*MAIN_TABLE* не получается всех строк.

Comment: если вам не все колонки нужны select distinct m.ew1, f.WORD_SATELLITE as WORD_SATELLITE .a если  вам все колонки нужны тогда Используйте Common table Expression , Temp query

Comment: А вот такой запрос, только что придумал:           
                 *select m.**, 
  c.WORD_SATELLITE from MAIN_TABLE m
left join (select WORD_SATELLITE, MAIN_TABLE_ID from FEATURES where DESCRIPTION = 'satellite') c
on m.FEATURES_ID = c.MAIN_TABLE_ID
*  
Вроде делает, то что нужно...

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо прописать требуемое условие внутри джойна:

```
select distinct m.*, f.WORD_SATELLITE as WORD_SATELLITE 
  from MAIN_TABLE m
       left join FEATURES f ON m.FEATURES_ID = f.MAIN_TABLE_ID
                           and f.DESCRIPTION = 'satellite'
order by m.ID
```